# CHM vs css+background

Tags: css, image, background, chm

I create CHM help file.
For decorate it I use css and option 'background'.
All my images saved in img.
My css setting for header like this:

```
.data{
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#fff url(/img/bg_fill.png) repeat-x;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="data">Hello world</div>
```

In HTML everything is OK, but when I make CHM file background does not have background.
Why? Maybe path is wrong? Somebody have simular problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I resolve my problem in my self.
During in experement I saw next sequence, when I add image in tag img and ny header is show.
I think whem CHM maked program does't add image into CHM file and all path is wrong. When I add images in div which hide - all resources is add and show my header.

Answer (score 1):

That's problem with the img path. I suspect img folder is in the same directory where  your css and html files are located. If so, try to remove first slash in image url: `url(img/...`

Answer (score 0):

Just simple solution is we just need to provide full path like where the image is located like C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\Images...